# Record exists when it doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Given this simple model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :topic, presence: true

  before_create :some_filter

private

  def some_filter
    self.noframe = false
  end
end
```

And the fact that there are:

- no observers
- no indexes on the "noframe" column

**How is this possible?**

```
attrs = { title: "a", url: "http://www.example.com", topic: "test" }

Article.where(attrs).count
=> 0

Article.where(url:"http://www.example.com").count
=> 0

article = Article.new(attrs)
article.save

(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Article Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."url" = 'http://www.example.com' LIMIT 1
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK

article.errors.full_messages
[]
```

**The debugger**

When putting the debugger inside of "some_filter" method, this is what's happening.

```
[12] pry(#<Article>)> self.noframe = nil
=> nil

[13] pry(#<Article>)> self.valid?
  Article Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."url" = 'http://www.example.com' LIMIT 1
=> true

[14] pry(#<Article>)> self.noframe = false
=> false

[15] pry(#<Article>)> self.valid?
  Article Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."url" = 'http://www.example.com' LIMIT 1
=> true

[16] pry(#<Article>)> self.save
  Article Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."url" = 'http://www.example.com' LIMIT 1
=> false
```

**More information**

To make it more interesting, when I change "some_filter" to set noframe to either nil or to true, I can create as many records as I want without "Article Exists" error.

It also works when I set noframe attribute directly and not inside of before_create filter.

**Why is this workaround working?**

I'm able to "fix" it by replacing "before_create" with "after_create" and updating the noframe attribute additionally with update_attributes(noframe:false). But why is this a solution? update_attributes also calls all callbacks and validation so why is this not working in before_create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`before_create` has one not that obvious property - if it returns false value it terminates whole saving chain. Same applies to all `before-*` callbacks. You can find it in [callback documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Canceling+callbacks). Your method returns false, so whole transaction rolls back. Change it to:

```
def some_filter
  self.noframe = false
  true
end
```

And all will work.

Comment: Makes sense. A less confusing error message would be nice though. I've filed a bug report: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22713